# Sending 'secure' financial statements on S3

Tags: python, security, amazon-s3

I need to provide individuals with their financial statement, and I am using S3. So far what I am doing is making the file `public-read` and creating a unique `Key`, using `uuid.uuid4()`.

Would this be acceptable, or how else could I make this more secure? Sending authentication keys for each individual is not an option.

Comment: Be very careful with the permissions on the bucket itself, if you go with this route -- don't let arbitrary users (or anyone, for that matter) list the bucket contents.

Comment: As far as I know, S3 cannot be coerced to require (or use at all) SSL/HTTPS;  If your users view statements over wifi at a public hotspot then the unencrypted statements could be viewed without the intended user's knowledge or consent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered generating expiring urls for the files on S3.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, is_secure=False)

# The generated temp_url remains valid for 60 seconds in this case
temp_url = conn.generate_url(60, 'GET', bucket=bucket_name, 
                             key=file_name, force_http=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a user authentication and login system in place, you can greatly increase security by handing out PDF links that link to *your site* and then redirecting to an S3 url created using [Query String Request Authentication](https://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) (aka "temporary urls").

Lets assume you have the following:

- `financial-statements` S3 bucket containing your PDFs. The bucket and all pdfs are marked `authenticated-read`.
- `financial-statement-reader` S3 user with its own access key `ABCDEFGaccesskeyid`
- The url `https://example.org/u/12345/statements/2011-04`. This is a page on a web site you control, and which cannot be accessed unless the customer is authenticated against your web site's authentication system.

Here's how this would work:

1. Create financial statement pdf and upload to s3: `https://financial-statements.s3.amazonaws.com/12345_2011-04.pdf`  Right now only S3-authenticated users can download the pdf, not your customer.
2. Give the url `https://example.org/u/12345/statements/2011-04` to your customer as their "April 2011 Financial Statement" url.
3. Customer GETs this url and authenticates against your web site if necessary.
4. You mint a Query String Request Authentication URL for `12345_2011-04.pdf` using the access key `ABCDEFGaccesskeyid` and an expiration time 30 seconds in the future. You end up with a link that looks like this: `https://financial-statements.s3.amazonaws.com/12345_2011-04.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ABCDEFGaccesskeyid&expires=1175139620&
   Signature=rucSbH0yNEcP9oM2XNlouVI3BH4%3D`
5. You reply to the customer's GET request with HTTP 307 (Temporary Redirect), `Cache-control: private,max-age=30`, and `Location: https://financial-statements.s3.amazonaws.com/12345_2011-04.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ABCDEFGaccesskeyid&expires=1175139620&
   Signature=rucSbH0yNEcP9oM2XNlouVI3BH4%3D`
6. Customer downloads their PDF directly from S3. If someone malicious steals this url they can download the customer's statements only within 30 seconds, after which the url becomes useless.

Comment: Another way to do what is outlined above is to use federated access. When someone authenticates on your server, you generate temporary federated awsid, secret and token which allows them to access files. Then your site can use these temp credentials to generate web pages for the client with time limited download links, etc. This has the effect of keeping your master keys in one small section of code  -which could be on a separate server, even.

Answer (score 1):

Even though version 4 UUIDs are supposed to incorporate random data, I wouldn't want to rely on the fact that the RNG used by Python's `uuid.uuid4()` being securely random. The Python docs make no mention about the quality of the randomness, so I'd be afraid that you might end up with guessable UUID's.

I'm not a crypto expert, so I won't suggest a specific alternative, but I would suggest using something that is designed to produce crypto-quailty random data, and transform that into something that can be used as an S3 key (I'm not sure what the requirements on S3 key data might be, but I'd guess they're supposed to be something like a filename).

To be honest, having no security other than an unguessable name still leaves me with a bad feeling. It seems to easy to have an unintentional leak of the names, as Ian Clelland suggests in his comment.

Comment: All security is based on an unguessable name. https, ssh, passwords, they all are based on that. That said, I don't think that the bill should be downloadable for ever at the passed url.

Comment: You're right. I guess I should have said an unguessable S3 key.